# How to update Nextjs component when data changes on the database without any button or what so

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I just want to see any update on the component whenever the data from the database is changes. Just like for example a listview component with data from the database, if I change it manually from the database without any interaction on the site, I want it to change just like in flutter it has StreamBuilder or some sort of way to listen changes from the database without any sorts of button

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this problem?
My thinking is to use something like socket.io or just a setInterval on the client app